# FFMpeg custom metadata not showing up using c++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to add a custom metadata to a video recording using C++.
`av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "title", "Cloud Recording", 0);`
works fine and shows up in properties->details tab for the mp4 file in windows

But doing:
`av_dict_set(&pMetaData, "random", "Cloud Recording", 0);`
doesn't work.

Does anyone know what to do to write a custom metadata to a mp4 file using c++?

```
AVFormatContext *outContext;
av_dict_set(&outContext->metadata, "random", "Cloud Recording", 0);
avformat_write_header(outContext, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you coming here for answer, this works:

```
AVDictionary* opts = NULL;
av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "use_metadata_tags", 0);
av_dict_set(&outContext->metadata, "random", "Cloud Recording", 0);
avformat_write_header(outContext, &opts);
av_dict_free(&opts);
```

This adds custom metadata to file header.